# Recording Video on a Long Press Gesture

Tags: ios, iphone, video, avfoundation

I currently have an application that allows me to take a picture and display it to the user with some filtering applied to it.

I also have a preview layer that shows the user a live stream of what the camera is currently seeing. If a user taps the preview, an image is taken and if they tap again, they are taken back to the live stream.

This is working well but now, I'd like to be able to do the same thing with a video and instead of a tap, I'd like to use a long press similar to what apps like Vine used to do to record. At the moment, I am able to record a video using this method and save it to my device. I am sure that my recording is working because I am able to see it by downloading my apps container and viewing its temporary files.

I'd like to be able to take the video and once my finger is released, present the video to the user and if tapped again, present them with the live stream again in order to start it all over.

Here is the code for my long press gesture:

```
func longPressView(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if(isRecording) {
            takeVideo();
        }
        isRecording = false;

        if(longPressGesture?.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.cancelled ||
            longPressGesture?.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.failed ||
            longPressGesture?.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended) {
            videoFileOutput?.stopRecording();
        }
    }
```

Here are my delegate functions:

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt fileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!) {
        print("You started recording!");
    }

func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
        print("Finished recording: \(outputFileURL)");
        videoFileOutput?.stopRecording();
        getVideo(outputFileURL: outputFileURL as NSURL);
    }
```

For reference, with the still image shot, I used the following delegate:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imageOutput = self.getImageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: sampleBuffer);
        }
    }
```

I would then just set the imageOutput variable equal to my imageViews image in order to show the still to the user.

Any idea on how I can present the user with a preview of the video they just took?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE: 4-3-2017**

Here is my Class definition with its instance variables:

```
class Camera: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var dataOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?
    var imageOutput: UIImage?
    var videoFileOutput: AVCaptureMovieFileOutput?;

    var didTakePhoto = Bool();
    var isRecording: Bool = true;
```

Also, my viewWillAppear method:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession();
        captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;

        let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo);

        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera);

            if (captureSession?.canAddInput(input))! {
                captureSession?.addInput(input);

                dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput();
                dataOutput?.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)];
                dataOutput?.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true;

                if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(dataOutput))! {
                    captureSession?.addOutput(dataOutput);

                    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession);
                    previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
                    previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait;
                    cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!);
                    captureSession?.startRunning();

                    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.RafaelNegron");
                    dataOutput?.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue);
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are you using for capturing video..? Implementing your own class with AVCaptureSession or using any third-party ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm implementing my own class with AVCaptureSession. I've gone ahead and added some more code snippets for clarity. Thanks.